# Oracle Trigger - ERROR: ORA-00903: invalid table name

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a problem with my sql code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER
BEFORE UPDATE ON TABAPPOGGIO
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
ERRORE EXCEPTION;
begin
IF :NEW_ConteggioPrenotazioni>150
THEN RAISE ERRORE;
END IF;
exception
when errore then raise_application_error (-20002, 'Sala Piena');
end;
```

I created a query before, for tabappoggio:

```
CREATE VIEW TABAPPOGGIO
AS
SELECT COUNT(Codice) AS ConteggioPrenotazioni
FROM PRENOTAZIONI
WHERE Sala='101'
GROUP BY Codice
```

But it keeps telling me ORA-00903: invalid table name.
Any help, please, or suggestions? Thanks!

EDIT: SORRY!!! I accidentally deleted a comment of someone who told me I forgot the trigger name. I saw the tick mark and clicked it but... I failed. Sorry, I still need to realize how buttons work, I am pretty new here.
ANYWAY THANK YOU!!! I literally forgot the trigger name as a fool. I didn't realize, all in panic. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Is your Table 'TABAPPOGGIO' created?

Comment: You are missing the name of the trigger, and `:NEW_ConteggioPrenotazioni` should be `:NEW.ConteggioPrenotazioni`, but the question is: what should this do? I believe that even if you fix these syntax issues, this will not do what you need. Please post what you need to do to get a better help

Comment: The trigger aside, what would you expect `update TABAPPOGGIO set ConteggioPrenotazioni = 100` to do? That there are suddenly exactly 100 records for Sala = '101' in PRENOTAZIONI?

Comment: Basically I need to check on prenotations! If the number of prenotations overflows the number of actual possible prenotations (ex. there are 150 seats so I can make 150 prenotations, and when someone else adds a prenotation, so it makes 151, it raises error). 
In fact, it doesn't actually do what it should do. Shame on me, sob. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

You need `INSTEAD OF` trigger if you want to create a trigger on view. 
INSTEAD OF triggers are valid for `DML` events on views. They are not valid for `DDL` or database events.

Demo

```
CREATE TABLE BaseTable
  (ID     int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
   Color          nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
   Material       nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
   ComputedCol AS (Color + Material)
  );


--Create a view that contains all columns from the base table.
CREATE VIEW InsteadView
AS SELECT ID, Color, Material, ComputedCol
FROM BaseTable;


--Create an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger on the view.
CREATE TRIGGER InsteadTrigger on InsteadView
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO BaseTable
       SELECT Color, Material
       FROM inserted
END;
```

In your case it becomes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER InsteadTrigger on  TABAPPOGGIO
INSTEAD OF UPDATE OR INSERT
DECLARE
ERRORE EXCEPTION;
begin
IF :NEW.ConteggioPrenotazioni>150
THEN RAISE ERRORE;
END IF;
exception
when errore then raise_application_error (-20002, 'Sala Piena');
end;
```

Note: You can read both the :OLD and the :NEW value, but you cannot write either the :OLD or the :NEW value.

Answer (score 1):

You code has some syntax issues, but the main issue is that, if I understand your need, it will not do what you expect.

If I correctly interpret you need, you want to prevent inserting more than 150 rows in a table with a given value of `sala`.
If so you can simply build a trigger on the table to check, performing the count after having inserted one or more rows.

For example:

```
create table PRENOTAZIONI( sala varchar2(10), codice number);

create or replace trigger checkPrenotazioni
after insert on prenotazioni
declare
    vNum   number;
    ERRORE EXCEPTION;
begin
    select count(codice)
    into vNum
    from prenotazioni
    where sala = '101';
    --
    IF vNum >150
        THEN RAISE ERRORE;
    END IF;
exception
    when errore
        then raise_application_error (-20002, 'Sala Piena');    
end;
```

Now I insert 150 rows with `sala = '101'` and everything goes well:

```
SQL> insert into prenotazioni(sala, codice) select '101', 101 from dual connect by level <= 150;

150 rows created.
```

If I try to insert the 151th row, the row is not inserted and I have:

```
SQL> insert into prenotazioni(sala, codice) values ('101', 101);
insert into prenotazioni(sala, codice) values ('101', 101)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20002: Sala Piena
ORA-06512: at "ALEK.CHECKPRENOTAZIONI", line 15
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ALEK.CHECKPRENOTAZIONI'

SQL> select count(1) from prenotazioni;

  COUNT(1)
----------
       150

SQL>
```

Same thing if I try to insert 151 rows in one shot:

```
SQL> truncate table prenotazioni;

Table truncated.

SQL> select count(1) from prenotazioni;

  COUNT(1)
----------
         0

SQL> insert into prenotazioni(sala, codice) select '101', 101 from dual connect by level <= 151;
insert into prenotazioni(sala, codice) select '101', 101 from dual connect by level <= 151
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20002: Sala Piena
ORA-06512: at "ALEK.CHECKPRENOTAZIONI", line 15
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ALEK.CHECKPRENOTAZIONI'
```

Comment: Your trigger works, but I tried the insert part, but there's ''unique costraint violated'' error. Probably because of how I created the table?

Comment: I tried to insert some test records without knowing your table structure, so probably my data  does not match your structure. However, this is only for testing you can build your test case to matc your structure

Comment: Also, if one of the answers you've had is right for you, please accept it; This is both a way to mark the question as closed and to say thanks to people who helped you. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you find something more on what to do when someone answers you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are thinking too complicated. You want to restrict records in the table `PRENOTAZIONI`, so write an insert trigger for that table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_too_many_prenotazioni
AFTER INSERT ON prenotazioni
DECLARE
  v_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
  select count(*) into v_count from prenotazioni where sala = 101;
  IF v_count > 150 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'sala piena');
  END IF;
END trg_too_many_prenotazioni;
```

(And maybe you want a `SALA` table with a record per `sala` and a column for the number of allowed `prenotazioni` rather then hard-coding 150 for sala = 101 here.)